# Gstreamer converting mp4 to av1 & Opus codecs

Tags: c++, audio, gstreamer

I really need your help.

I should write a C++ tool using GStreamer that takes mp4 file, takes its video stream and converts it to the AV1 codec, converts the audio of the video to the Opus codec, mux them together and save them in an MKV container.

For now, I wrote this code:

```cpp
#include <gst/gst.h>

static void on_pad_added(GstElement* decodebin, GstPad* pad, gpointer data) {
    GstPad* sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(GST_ELEMENT(data), "sink");
    GstPadLinkReturn ret = gst_pad_link(pad, sinkpad);
    gst_object_unref(sinkpad);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    // Create pipeline and elements
    GstElement* pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("video-pipeline");
    GstElement* filesrc = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "file-source");
    GstElement* decodebin = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decode-bin");
    GstElement* av1enc = gst_element_factory_make("av1enc", "av1-encoder");
    GstElement* filesink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", "file-sink");

    // Set input and output file locations
    const char* inputFileName = "../input.mp4";
    const char* outputFileName = "output.mkv";
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filesrc), "location", inputFileName, NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filesink), "location", outputFileName, NULL);

    // Link the elements
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), filesrc, decodebin, av1enc, filesink, NULL);
    gst_element_link(filesrc, decodebin);
    gst_element_link(decodebin, av1enc);
    gst_element_link(av1enc, filesink);

    // Connect to the "pad-added" signal of decodebin to dynamically link the decoder to the encoder
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(decodebin), "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(on_pad_added), av1enc);

    // Set caps on av1enc element
    GstCaps* caps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw",
                                        "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "YUV",
                                        NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(av1enc), "caps", caps, NULL);
    gst_caps_unref(caps);

    // Set pipeline state to PLAYING
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    // Wait for the EOS message or handle other events/messages
    GstBus* bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
    GstMessage* msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GstMessageType(GST_MESSAGE_EOS | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR));

    if (msg != NULL) {
        if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg) == GST_MESSAGE_ERROR) {
            GError* error;
            gchar* debug_info;
            gst_message_parse_error(msg, &error, &debug_info);
            g_printerr("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME(msg->src), error->message);
            g_printerr("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
            g_clear_error(&error);
            g_free(debug_info);
        } else if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg) == GST_MESSAGE_EOS) {
            g_print("End of stream reached.\n");
        }

        gst_message_unref(msg);
    }

    // Clean up and exit
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(pipeline));
    gst_deinit();

    return 0;
}
```

Hovewer, for some reason, it runs forever, and I can't understand why. Please, explain why it can happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are not even error checking your commands. `decodebin` cannot be connected until data flow starts.

Check the GStreamer Example No. 3 Dynamic Pipelines as an example:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/dynamic-pipelines.html?gi-language=c

But what exactly means forever? AV1 encoding may be quite CPU intensive.